# Azure Resoure Manager, Failed to delete resource group error

Tags: azure, resources

While deleting a resource group am getting the below mentioned error.

> Failed to delete resource group backupone: Deletion of resource group
>   'backupone' failed as resources with identifiers
>   'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupone' could not be deleted.
>   The provisioning state of the resource group will be rolled back. The
>   tracking Id is 'ee14d432-edf4-48e3-ba7f-016757125909'. Please check
>   audit logs for more details. (Code: ResourceGroupDeletionBlocked)
>   Vault cannot be deleted as there are existing resources within the
>   vault. Please ensure there are no backup items, protected servers or
>   backup management servers associated with this vault. Unregister the
>   following containers associated with this vault before proceeding for
>   deletion : backuponestg Unregister all containers from the vault and
>   then retry to delete vault (Code:
>   ServiceResourceNotEmptyWithContainerDetails)

Can someone please help me understand what is wrong?

Comment: "Vault cannot be deleted as there are existing resources within the vault" hints to me that there might be a Azure Site Recovery Vault in the resource group. Is this the case? If so, then you need to delete all virtual machines it manages (backup and replicated) . **Note:** not the actual virtual machines, just the data inside of ASR.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented above, the error message

> Vault cannot be deleted as there are existing resources within the vault

hints to me there might be a Azure Site Recovery Vault in the resource group.

Here's some more information.

If you got a Azure Site Recovery Vault inside of a resource group, and it contains some data from backed up virtual machines, then this can block the deletion of the vault.

You need to, manually, first to clean up the vault before you can delete the ASR vault. This is a mechanism set in place to prevent accidental deletion of backed up data.

Check out this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/delete-vault) for a more detailed guide on what steps you need to take to unassociate workloads with your vault.